# jquery function is not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have placed a repeater enveloped in a div inside an update panel.and add a jquery function in the  of page to add some effect on it. the jquery function is called on every page_load event. it is working well n a test page but doesn't show any effect when I implement it in the master page my jquery function is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function pageLoad(sender, args) {
            // JQuery code goes here
            function domReady() {
                $('#btn1').click(showMessage);
                $('#btn1').trigger('click');
            }
                  function showMessage() {
                 $('#message').fadeOut(10);

                $('#message').slideDown(1000);

            };

     $(domReady);
};
</script>}
```

and html is

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="5000" ontick="Timer1_Tick">
        </asp:Timer>
        <br />
        <div style="height:480px;overflow:scroll;">
        <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
       <ItemTemplate>

                    <div id="message" >
                   <img id="image" alt="visitors" runat="server" src="~/icon-visitors.png" height="32" width="32" /></td><td>
                      <b>A New visitor come from </b><b class="data"><%#Eval("lt_country") %></b> &nbsp;&nbsp;<%#Eval("pk_id") %> <br />
                   &nbsp; <b>Ip :- </b><%#Eval("lt_ip") %><b>/ Browser :-</b><%#Browser(Eval("lt_browser").ToString()) %><b>/ 
                   Operating System :</b><%#Os(Eval("lt_browser").ToString()) %><br /><br />
                    </div>
               </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
       <button id="btn1" style="visibility:hidden;"></button>
       </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Is the jQuery script referenced in the master page?

Comment: are you implementing it on your master page? are you sure this js code is running when all the html is already rendered?

Comment: Check whether your domReady is working with the help of alert.

Comment: @karl,@gonzalo I am new to jquery i don't gave refrence in master page how to do it ???

Comment: That's not going to work if you have more than one item in your repeater.  You're only supposed to have one instance of an element on a page with a specific id.  In your case, you'd have one per RepeaterItem.  I also don't see where the `pageLoad` javascript function is being called.

Comment: @SaranyaSadhasivam my domready is working i check it

Comment: @ps2goat i check it on test page it was working perfectly with same html and jquery

Comment: what you want to do please explain.. so that we can provide you some alternate solutions to that if the above is not working

Comment: without us seeing the new code, we can't help you.  Like others said, we don't even know if the script is on the master page (.master file)

Comment: @ps2goat script is on content page

Comment: @raman repeater is bound tto database i want it to check for updates in every 5 seconds so I placed it inside an update panal with a timer which is set to 5 seconds. when a record is updated on tick event jquery funtion domready is run and show slide down effect on updated record.

Answer (score 0):

In the repeater, instead of using id to the button and div, use class. Because id should be unique. It will not work if you give id.

Your script and html should be changed as below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function pageLoad(sender, args) {
            // JQuery code goes here
            function domReady() {
                $('#btn1').click(showMessage);
                $('#btn1').trigger('click');
            }
                  function showMessage() {
                 $('.message').fadeOut(10);

                $('.message').slideDown(1000);

            };

     $(domReady);
};
</script>

<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
       <ItemTemplate>

                    <div class="message" >
                   <img id="image" alt="visitors" runat="server" src="~/icon-visitors.png" height="32" width="32" /></td><td>
                      <b>A New visitor come from </b><b class="data"><%#Eval("lt_country") %></b> &nbsp;&nbsp;<%#Eval("pk_id") %> <br />
                   &nbsp; <b>Ip :- </b><%#Eval("lt_ip") %><b>/ Browser :-</b><%#Browser(Eval("lt_browser").ToString()) %><b>/ 
                   Operating System :</b><%#Os(Eval("lt_browser").ToString()) %><br /><br />
                    </div>
               </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
       <button id="btn1" style="visibility:hidden;"></button>
```